# Sharding empty collection taking a very long time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

(I am using Mongo 3.2.4)

When I shard an empty collection it is taking around 100 seconds.  Example of command entered:

```
sh.shardCollection("db_rel.timeseries3", {location:1, shard:1, start:1, end:1})
```

It should be noted that we use shard tags pin data to a specific region, e.g. London, New York, Hong Kong.

When I tail the mongos logs I can see the shard command and that it has this:

```
going to create 1 chunk(s) for: db_rel.timeseries3
```

Then:

```
ChunkManager: time to load chunks for ddp_rel.timeseries3: 90ms sequenceNumber: 12102 version: 1|0||58c6e0ea395448d97cb66ba8 based on: (empty)
```

So far this seems sensible.  But I then see the ChunkManager goes through other collections in the data, of which there are 100s, doing the same thing.  Each one takes around 200ms, which adds up to taking are very long time in total.

I believe (but can't find documentation for this) that it is because the collections are empty (the final part of the logging states ' based on: (empty)').  When I shard a new collection, the ChunkManager wakes up and tries to distribute the data in the other collections, however because they are empty it doesn't know which region to migrate to.

Is someone able to confirm above hypothesis?

Is there a way to tag the initial chunks to a location to prevent ChunkManager going through all collections? Or some other workaround?

As we are going to be creating > 10,000 collections, it is not feasible to have each shard command on the new empty collection take > 100 seconds.

Comment: There was a bug in the shard tag whereby only the collection name rather than namspace (includes the database name) was being inserted into config.tags collection.

Comment: The ChunkManager still seems to come alive and go through every sharded collection in the database when I shard a new collection, but now  each collection only takes 1 ms.  As FYI, I tried adding data to collections, and I can see that the ChunkManager still calls the collection so the "based on (empty)" was misleading.  Any info on why every collection is checked would be appreciated, and if possible how to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a known issue, and is fixed in Mongo 3.4:
[Mongo DB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22611)

Comment: Confirmed fixed in 3.4.4